# Export excel using openoffice in c# win form

Tags: c#, excel, datagrid, openoffice-calc

I am working on window application and I want to export data from datagridview to spread sheet, How can I export it without using Microsoft Excel dll.
I searched about openoffice but could not found a proper solution for window form.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain third party libraries, such as Essential Studio XlsIO (.NET library).

Samples: [XlsIO](http://asp.syncfusion.com/sfaspnetsamplebrowser/8.4.0.10/Web/XlsIO.Web/samples/4.0/)

Comment: is there any free library to use?

Comment: CarlosAg Excel Xml Writer Library, Smart Excel Lib (http://smartexcel.sourceforge.net/), another free lib (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28795/Very-Simple-Library-to-Work-with-Excel-in-NET)

Answer (score 0):

I used google Excel library for this.

Add [Excel library](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/downloads/detail?name=ExcelLibrary_20110730.zip) to your solution and use this code.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

//Set the locale for each 
ds.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
dt1.Locale = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

dt1 = Extensions.AsDataTable(objEntityDataModel.smme_campaign_report(campId));
ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

//set the campaign name and create word file
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(@"d:\\" + campaignName + ".xlsx", ds);
```